# Is there a way I can see the histograms shared in xgboost histogram tree training?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have built a simple xgboost model that uses hist as tree_method parameter. I wanted to know if there is a way that I can see the histogram info that is being shared during training? I tried to plot one of the trees but it only shows the splits, while I am looking to find which information holds at the leaf level.